# each dentro de otro each Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vistas, each

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Al consultar una coleccion en Rails necesito consultar otra coleccion dentro de esa misma colección, estoy intentando con each dentro de each pero no puedo recorrer bien mi colección.

Ejemplo:

```
<tbody id="tbody-partners">
   <% @partners.each do |partner| %>
      <tr id="partner_<%= partner.id %>">
          <td><%= partner.partner_company.name %></td>
          <td><%= partner.participation_percentage %></td>
          <td><%= partner.partner_company.rut %></td>
      </tr>
      <table class="table-display collapse" id="partner_table_<%= partner.id %>">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th scope="col">Socio</th>
               <th scope="col">% Part.</th>
               <th scope="col">RUT</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>

            <% @partners.each do |p| %>
               <tr>
                   <td><%= p.partner_company.name %></td>
                   <td><%= p.participation_percentage %></td>
                   <td><%= p.partner_company.rut %></td>
               </tr>
            <% end %>

         </tbody>
       </table>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

mi modelo de Partners es una tabla intermedia que guarda un :company_id y un :partner_company_id además de su :id y :participation_percentage

Una company tiene Partners y esos partners que son companies tienen partners que son companies.

quiero mostrar a los partners de los partners en la vista show de mi modelo company.

he intentado con

```
<% @partners.partner_company.each do |p| %>

<% partner.partner_company.each do |p| %>
```

Pero en realidad estoy bloqueado.

Editado...

```rb
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to  :partner_company, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'partner_company_id', optional: true
end
```

```
class Company < FilterableRecord
    has_many    :partners_company, class_name: 'Partner', foreign_key: 'debtor_company_id'
    has_many    :partners
end
```

y en mi controlador de partner

```
class PartnersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_company, only: [:create]
    
    def create
        @partner = Partner.new(partner_params[:partner])
        @partner.company = @company
        company = Company.find_or_create_by(partner_params[:company])
        @partner.partner_company = company
        respond_to do |format|
            if @partner.save
                format.js
            else
                format.html { redirect_to @company, 
                            notice: 'El socio no se pudo guardar' }
            end
        end
    end

    def set_company
        @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end
end
```

Y en mi controlador de Company los llamo con un callback

```
def set_partners
      @partners = @company.partners.page(params[:page]).per(6).order(created_at: :desc) if @company
end
```

aunque en ves de lógica en mi vista me gustaría hacer un hash para recorrer los valores y llamarlos en mi vista, aunque no se como hacer eso, sigo investigando.

Comment: tal vez esta respuesta te ayude, está en el sitio de SOes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/282109/8166997

Comment: ¿puedes compartir el código de tus modelos involucrados? específicamente de como se relacionan entre si, aparte del código involucrado que asigna un valor a `@partners`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas confundiendo un poco en lo que estas haciendo y las relaciones de tu base de datos.

Exclusivamente esta parte:

```
    <% partner.partner_company.each do |p| %>
```

En tu modelo estas diciendo que partner pertenece partner_company. Entonces no vas a poder iterar en esta relacion. Lo unico que vas a poder hacer es:

```
<%= partner.partner_company.field %>
```

Pero el problema radica en como estas generando la relacion. tu relacion esta incorrecta

```
Una company tiene Partners y esos partners que son companies tienen partners que son companies.
```

Lo que estas buscando es que una compania tenga partners que son companias. Por lo tanto estas buscando una relacion muchos a muchos sobre la misma tabla.

Puedes leer mas de esto aqui:

http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: La relación está correcta, el partner solo es un nombre y tiene valores especifico a cada compañia, al final uso al id de la compañia nueva creada la cual la tabla partner la ubica gracias a la foreign_key partner_company_id y basandome en esta id se guarda una nueva compañia que será socia de la anterior, al final es como los comentarios de los comentarios en facebook, un comentario está relacionado a un usuario y el comentario del comentario está relacionado al comentario anterior y así sucesivamente